# How to fix yocto package compilation issue Binutils 2.34

Tags: yocto

I am building yocto for begalbone black in linux mint.
I have tried bitbake -c cleansstate binutils then bitbake binutils but didn't fix the issue.

[Text] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ok6_AE_AY1j5wfasSBPA1nFj9ZZftSRx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `/bin/bash: pod2man: command not found` was in log, try installing pod2man and check

Comment: I expect the `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault` is more likely to be related to the real problem

Answer (score 0):

I have include following flag in local.conf to protect from stack overflow and updated to latest dunfell branch.
TARGET_CPPFLAGS += "-fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1"